# telerik numerictextbox and telerik date picker styling in asp page

Tags: telerik, datepicker, numeric-textbox

telerik numerictextbox and telerik date picker styling in asp page.
i want to change background color ,border color of telerik rad textbox, rad datepicker
.please help me i have try to do it by using style="....." but not working .
thanks in advance

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBox3" width="145px" runat="server"></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>

<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

please help me............

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the Control's properties?

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="myNumTextBox" runat="server" 
            BackColor="Yellow" BorderColor="Red">
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="myDatePicker" runat="server"
            BackColor="Yellow" BorderColor="Red"
            Calendar-CalendarTableStyle-BorderColor="Red"
            Calendar-CalendarTableStyle-BackColor="Yellow"
            Calendar-DayStyle-BorderColor="Red"
            Calendar-DayStyle-BackColor="Yellow"
            Calendar-FastNavigationStyle-BorderColor="Red"
            Calendar-FastNavigationStyle-BackColor="Yellow"
            DateInput-BorderColor="Red"
            DateInput-BackColor="Yellow">
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

For the DatePicker, I presume you want the input field's `BackColor` and `BorderColor`, so use the `DateInput-` properties.